# Putting the symbol hat over greek letter in text mode

Tags: text

In latex text mode \^{} puts hat on characters but i need to put hat on greek letters in text mode. How can I put the symbol hat over a greek letter in text mode?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by text mode, you could employ inline math, as in `text $\^{}$ more text`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking on `textgreek` package it generally will not work in `math-mode` except when you use special macros. My modest suggestion for to have Greek characters in text mode, you should use in mathematical mode, `upgreek` package. In particular I have used the commands

`\hat` and `\widewat`

to have a comparison.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
$\hat{\upalpha}, \widehat{\upalpha}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the inline command to switch to math mode, such as 
`$\hat{\tilde{a}}$`
and continue with the text.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: By writing $\hat{\alpha}$ I got alpha hat in text. Thanks for the answer.